# How to delete non-system apps from android using adb?

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to write a script to clean up android devices before some automated tasks. So I'm looking for some way to remove all the non-system apps from the phone, using adb, as I continuously find that people love installing heavy games on those devices. (These are our work devices) :D I couldn't find anything useful till now, as most questions I found were about deleting the system apps.

I am able to list all the installed apps using adb

```
adb -s <device id> shell pm list packages -f | cut -d '=' -f 2
```

But that gives all the apps that are installed, including some of these:

```
com.android.backupconfirm
com.android.packageinstaller
com.android.providers.userdictionary
com.android.providers.downloads.ui
com.android.externalstorage
com.google.android.nfcprovision
com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.docs
com.google.android.apps.cloudprint
```

I'm afraid, if I accidentally uninstall them, the phone will become useless.
Can someone suggest a way to delete only the applications installed by others ?

Comment: You cant uninstall system apps without requesting root permissions so you should not have to worry about doing something dangerous.

Comment: `adb shell pm list packages -s` lists system apps. Presumably, you could use that as a source of filtering data -- anything in the main list that is not in the `-s` list should be a non-system app.

Comment: non system apps are uninstalled by `adb uninstall com.example.yourapp`

Comment: if you already have a new device provisioning script - make sure to incorporate a factory reset into the procedure and use that instead. Let users worry about saving the data they don't want to lose.

Answer (score 2):

```
for pkg in $(adb shell pm list packages -3 | cut -d: -f2); do
  adb uninstall $pkg
done
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.